# How firebase listener actually work?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering on Android, how the underlying actual mechanism work when you add an listener to the database. Is it just more frequent pulling or something else special?

**Update:** 
To make it clearer, I understand what a listener is, but I meant how does the 'listening' scheme work, how a client (Android) knows the data on the server changed. Is it just a periodical pulling? (and Firebase engineers already do the hard work to cover that and make it easy for us).

Looks like firebase is not open-source.

```
// Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*disclaimer: this is a simplified description of how things work at the time of writing. Things may have changed by the time your read it.*

When your app connects to the Firebase Database, it opens a web socket connection from the device to a Firebase server. This connection stays open for the lifetime of your app or until you call `goOffline()`.

When you attach a listener, the client sends the location (and potential query parameters) to the server. The server adds that listener to a list of all listeners of all connected clients. It then also sends back the initial data for that listeners.

Whenever a write operation is committed to the database, the server scans the listeners. For each relevant listener, the server sends an update to the client over the open web socket.

Comment: I marked as answer but don't know it'll still be valid in the future like you said :)

Comment: What happens when persistence mode is enabled? Because events are still fired when a local state changes and you are offline..

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2019?

Comment: Yup. This is still substantially how it works. If you have a problem that might be related, open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**It happens Asynchronously**

**Adding listeners to a node reference will fetch any changes made to the node reference asynchronously**

**void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)**

This method will be called with a snapshot of the data at this location. It will also be called each time that data changes.

**void onCancelled(FirebaseError error)**

This method will be triggered in the event that this listener either failed at the server, or is removed as a result of the security and Firebase rules. For more information on securing your data, see: Security Quickstart

Example

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class) //This is your POJO class
    String name = users.getName(); //Other getter methods to fetch data from firbase


}
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you, but I want to view how the listener from Android (client) knows the data on the central firebase changed.

Comment: The changes will be asynchronous, that is where the event listeners come into picture

Answer (score -1):

It's explained in the guide [Firebase - Retrieve Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to view how the listener from Android (client) knows the data on the central firebase changed.