# addListenerForSingleValueEvent is fired multiple times

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database in my app. I am using addListenerForSingleValueEvent Listner to update data in my data base. I found that the data isn't updating correctly and after debugging the code I found that the listener has worked for 5 times !!!

```
            if (player1Score == player2Score) {
            player1Reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.v("pointsDebug", "onDataChanged1");
                    long points = (long) dataSnapshot.child("points").getValue();
                    usersReference.child(player1Uid).child("points").setValue(points + 1);

                    usersReference.removeEventListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            player2Reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.v("pointsDebug", "onDataChanged2");
                    long points = (long) dataSnapshot.child("points").getValue();
                    usersReference.child(player2Uid).child("points").setValue(points + 1);

                    usersReference.removeEventListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

and this is the repeated log :

```
10-20 17:03:43.841 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged1
10-20 17:03:43.841 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged2
10-20 17:03:43.881 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged1
10-20 17:03:43.881 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged2
10-20 17:03:43.921 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged1
10-20 17:03:43.921 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged2
10-20 17:03:43.971 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged1
10-20 17:03:43.971 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged2
10-20 17:03:44.691 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged1
10-20 17:03:44.701 19217-19217/com.mk.playAndLearn V/pointsDebug: onDataChanged2
```

The database structre is something like that :

```
users
   -user1
        -....
   -user2
        -.....
```

Comment: Can we see the database structure? Also, which listener are you talking about ?

Comment: @Mohsen both the listeners repeated . I will updated the question now

Comment: I've never seen a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` fire multiple times. It's of course always possible that you're seeing a bug. But the code gives no indication of that. You might want to add some logging each time right when you call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, to see if you aren't attaching listeners more frequently than you expect to.

Answer (score 1):

The best and the ideal approach to remove the listener is to do it based on the Android Life-cycle of the current `Activity`.

But, you are removing the listener inside the `onDataChange()`. I guess that's why this happens.

Either remove this line: `usersReference.removeEventListener(this);` from `onDataChange()` or, remove the listener inside `onDestory()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    usersReference.removeEventListener(YourActivity.this);
}
```

Android will do the rest.

Comment: why I can't remove the listener in OnDataChanged

Comment: I suggest [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279329/how-firebase-listener-actually-work). I've never seen removing the listener inside `onDataChange()` since it's asynchronously run the listener and there is also `onCancelled()` method after that. You can however, remove the listener after it has been used and did the work like after `onCancelled()` or removing it when `Activity` destroyed (like mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Do I need to remove singleEventListeners or I can remove this line ?

Comment: Remove that line from `onDataChange()` and use it after the listener finished it work. Or, like I said in my answer, add it inside `onDestroy()` method. Then try to see what happens.